# How do I use fetched backbone collection data in another view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Trying to learn Backbone and hitting a stumbling block when trying to fetch data, I fetch the data fine from with my view `SearchBarView` but once the data has been fetched I don't know how I can get this data in my SearchResultsView in order to template out each result?

Sorry if this sounds a little vague, struggling to get my head around this at the moment so could do with the guidance!

**SearchBarView**

```
performSearch: function(searchTerm) {

            // So trim any whitespace to make sure the word being used in the search is totally correct
            var search = $.trim(searchTerm);

            // Quick check if the search is empty then do nothing
            if(search.length <= 0) {
                return false;
            }

            // Make the fetch using our search term
            dataStore.videos.getVideos(searchTerm);

        },
```

**Goes off to VideoSearchCollection**

```
getVideos: function(searchTerm) {

            console.log('Videos:getVideos', searchTerm);

            // Update the search term property which will then be updated when the url method is run
            // Note make sure any url changes are made BEFORE calling fetch
            this.searchTerm = searchTerm;

            this.fetch();
        },
```

**SearchResultsView**

```
initialize: function() {

            // listens to a change in the collection by the sync event and calls the render method
            this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);

            console.log('This collection should look like this: ', this.collection);
        },


        render: function() {

            var self = this,
                gridFragment = this.createItems();

                this.$el.html(gridFragment);

            return this;
        },


        createItems: function() {

            var self = this,
                gridFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

                this.collection.each(function (video) {
                    var searchResultView = new SearchResultView({
                        'model': video
                    });

                    gridFragment.appendChild(searchResultView.el);

                }, this);


            return gridFragment;

        }
```

Now I'm not sure how I can get this data within `SearchResultView`, I think I need to trigger an event from somewhere and listen for the event in the `initialize` function but I'm not sure where I make this trigger or if the trigger is made automatically.

Comment: show code related to the `SearchResultView`

Comment: @coding_idiot I've added my code for SearchResultView, hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

If `dataStore` is a global variable then
    SearchBarView

```
dataStore - appears like a global variable
videos - a collection attached to global variable
```

then in

```
SearchResultsView

this.listenTo(dataStore.videos, 'sync', this.render);
```

**Solution 2**

If `dataStore` is not a global variable

```
getVideos: function(searchTerm) {

            console.log('Videos:getVideos', searchTerm);

            // Update the search term property which will then be updated when the url method is run
            // Note make sure any url changes are made BEFORE calling fetch
            this.searchTerm = searchTerm;

            var coll=this;       //this should refer to the collection itself
            this.fetch().done(function(){
                var searchResultView = new SearchResultsView({collection:coll});
                searchResultView.render();
            });
        },
```

Comment: that was it, i got really confused and was trying to trigger events etc instead of listening to the collections sync event. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not 100% clear how you are initializing your SearchResultView.

But, in order to have reference to the collection, can't you simply pass in the reference to the constructor of the view. Something like this:

// In your SearchbarView

```
var myCollection = new Backbone.Collection(); // and you are populating the collection somewhere somehow 
var searchResultView = new SearchResultView(myCollection) // you just pass this collection as argument.
myCollection.bind("change", function(){
   searchResultView.parentCollection = myCollection;
 }
```

And inside your searchResultView you just refer this collection by parentCollection for instance.

If you make it more explicit as in how these 2 views are connected or related, I may be able to help you more. But, with given info, this seems like the easiest way.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, yeah basically at the moment Im not sure how or where to initialize my SearchResultView like do I do it inside SearchBarView right after I make the fetch, or will the fetch emit an event I can listen for and pass the data. Ideally I want to then do // We then want to create our searchResults View using the collection set in dataStore for Films
            this.searchResults = new SearchResultsView({
                'collection': dataStore.videos
            });

Comment: You can initialize your view after the fetch and then you can update your collection in searchResultView whenever the collection is changed. This can be done by this code -- myCollection.bind("change", function(){
   searchResultView.collection = myCollection;
 }